# How to change selected navigation view item when navigating to other frames(UWP)?

Tags: uwp, navigationview

I have a UWP whose `MainPage` is a `NavigationView`.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="MyNavigationView"
                ItemInvoked="MyNavigationView_OnItemInvoked"
                >

    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="List" Content="Channels" Tag="channels"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Video" Content="Player" Tag="player"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <Frame x:Name="MyFrame">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>

</NavigationView>
```

As you can see, other two frames are `ChannelsPage` and `PlayerPage`. I list some channels in `ChannelsPage`, and by clicking one item, the frame will navigate to `PlayerPage`:

```
private void EachTvProgram_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var nextPlaying = (TvProgram) e.ClickedItem;
        TvProgramManager.PlayingProgram = nextPlaying.Title;

        ChannelDetails.IsPaneOpen = false;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(PlayerPage));
    }
```

Though page is navigated correctly, the `SelectedItem` in `NavigationView.MenuItem` is still `Channels`, how could I change it to `Player` in the function?

Explanation image here: [explanation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62i84.png)

As you can see, the frame is actually `PlayerPage` while the `SelectedItem` is `ChannelsPage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `public` method that sets the `SelectedItem` of the `NavigationView`.

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public void SetSelectedNavigationItem(int index)
{
    MyNavigationView.SelectedItem = MyNavigationView.MenuItems[index];
}
```

Now after you navigate to the `PlayerPage` you can do the following:

```
Frame appFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
MainPage mainPage = appFrame.Content as MainPage;
mainPage.SetSelectedNavigationItem( 1 );
```

Of course it would be better to have the access to the main page simpler like creating a `static` method on `MainPage`:

```
public static MainPage GetCurrent()
{
    Frame appFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    return appFrame.Content as MainPage;
}
```

Another improvement would be to create an enum to replace the "magical" index integer.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. The core here is to get Frame as MainPage in other Pages.

Comment: One thing to be careful with is that NavigationViewItemSeparators are included in the MenuItems, so remember to account for them in your index/enum value.